# code in playground won't work in a project

Tags: swift

this is my first post here having downloaded Xcode last week. I have never programmed before and it all started off well. I cannot seem to access variables outside of functions in a project, but it does work in the playground. Am I doing something wrong? The code is attached below.

```
func givenValue(number: Int) -> (small: Int, large: Int)
{
    let resultOne = (number*2)
    let resultTwo = (number * number)

    return (resultOne, resultTwo)
}

let answer = givenValue(15)

answer.small
answer.large
```

If i try this is the playground it all works well, if I attempt to use this in a project i get two errors as below:

"`cannot invoke 'givenValue' with an argument list of type '(Int)' "`

```
variable `"answer" flags up an expected declaration error.`
```

Thank you for any assistance, and my apologies if I formatted my question in the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

```
func givenValue(number: Int) -> (small: Int, large: Int)
{
 let resultOne = (number*2)
 let resultTwo = (number * number)

  return (resultOne, resultTwo)
}
```

In ViewDidLoad Call it

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     let answer = givenValue(15)

     answer.small
     answer.large
}
```

I hope it work!!!!!!

Comment: Yes that worked for me. One other question following this, can I then use ViewDidLoad to retrieve local variables? Thank you Memon.